# audio player that works when iOS screen is locked

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, audio-player

We tried a bunch of audio players for flutter, but none seem to be working when the screen is locked on iOS.

audio service doesn’t seem to work, video player neither.

We thought about using a web view in the meantime, but it doesn’t work either... :(

As soon as the screen locks, or as soon as we go to the home screen the audio stops.

Answer (score 3):

Your app must have the background audio mode. No code will make this work for you without it.

You can enable it by adding to add these lines to your app's info.plist file.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
    <string>audio</string>
 </array>
```